# Excel 2016 for mac trusted location

Tags: macos-sierra, office-js, excel-2016, excel-addins

How can i add, modify , delete a trusted location in Excel 2016 for Mac.
I was unable to locate the trust center in Excel 2016.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sideloading add-ins on Mac is a little different than on Windows. Here are the instructions: https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac

You'll need to follow those steps for every add-in that you want to sideload on Mac. Of course, the Office Store and your work/school organization catalog are both trusted by default too.

-Michael (PM for Office add-ins)

Comment: I am using the same method to load the office add-in.

Comment: I don't quite understand: did those instructions work correctly?

Comment: @Micheal - Yes.

Comment: Ah, that's great!

Comment: The link in the answer now appears to be dead.